# OneHotEncoding target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on a multiclass classifier with 6 classes on the target column and I was thinking about Hot Encoding the classes, thus having 6 target columns. Will this improve efficiency? I am using `sklearn`.

L.E: improve efficiency compared to just label encode

Comment: Improve with respect to what?

Comment: @Ben Reiniger yes, thank you.

Comment: @ncasas in respect to just label encode the classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a bad idea to use one hot encoding because this would make the problem [multi-label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification). This would make the problem much more complex for the model and would very likely lead to lower performance, or it would require much more data in order to reach the same performance as regular classification. This is because there are much more combinations possible in the multi-label problem: every instance can have any number of classes, from zero to all of them. Your training data would not have these cases, but the algorithm would assume that they can happen. So in your case this higher level of complexity is pointless since there can be only one class.

With scikit the standard way to encode the target in a multiclass task is to use the [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).